# Undefined array key 1

Tags: html, laravel

```
@foreach ( '$pegawai' => $pgw ) 
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Erbin Wiratama</td>
        <td>B09875</td>
        <td>example@example.org</td>
        <td>TSA NSA CORE</td>
        <td>
            <a href="button" class="btn btn-success">edit</a>
            <a href="button" class="btn btn-danger">delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This gives the following error.

```
Undifined Array Key 1
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, in `Laravel` 8. I'm beginner, Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: replace this line  "@foreach ( '$pegawai' => $pgw )"  with  "@foreach ( $pegawai as  $pgw )"

Comment: change or remove your email from the question

Comment: You are new to this site, but a lot of people tried to help your problem, so it would be nice to follow up on this or accept one of the answers as the correct one. Else this question would just be stale and not provide help to others with a similar problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
@foreach ( '$pegawai' => $pgw )
```

To this:

```
@foreach ( $pegawai as $pgw )
```

When you do foreach, it requires a collection to loop through. In your case, you're passing a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all a legal syntax.

```
@foreach ( '$pegawai' => $pgw )
```

Foreach expects an array, normally you would define it in the controller. This would let your array be available as `$pgw`.

```
public function yourView() {
    return view('yourview', ['pgw' => $pgw]);
}
```

And now you should be able to loop it like so.

```
@foreach ($pgw as $pegawai)
    <tr>
        <th>$pegawai</th>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @foreach ($pgw as $pegawai)
i do this syntax and the result is :

ErrorException
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given

Comment: What is the variable $pgw actually?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your syntax of foreach

Try the below code

```
@foreach ( $pegawai as $pgw ) 
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Erbin Wiratama</td>
    <td>B09875</td>
    <td>example@example.org/td>
    <td>TSA NSA CORE</td>
    <td>
    <a href="button" class="btn btn-success">edit</a>
    <a href="button" class="btn btn-danger">delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

@endforeach